# Is it necessary to free a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm using Boost library to benefit from the smart pointers : **shared_ptr**.

I suspect that in my unit test, i'm doing a bad assignment.

What are the drawbacks of my implementation, specially the instuction that has **//suspected** comment?

Do I need to **free shared_ptr** pointers (impossible to do in the way i'm assigning in my unit test, i guess)?

Any advice? Thanks a lot!

### In Class2 declaration:

```
static boost::shared_ptr<Class1> getInstanceOfClass1();
```

### In Class2 definition:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Class1> Class2::getInstanceOfClass1()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Class1> inst1 = boost::make_shared<Class1>();

    //.... some instructions on inst1

    return inst1 ;
}
```

### In a Unit Test using Boost.Test:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_some_label_here )
{
    string input;
    //instructions...
    // mocking the input
    //...

    Class1 a = *(Class2::getInstanceOfClass1()); //suspected
    int code = a.useInputAndReturnCode(input);

    // having CODE_X as a macro
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(code, CODE_X); 
}
```

Comment: In the test, why not simple use the `shared_ptr` returned? Now you have involvement of the copy-constructor which is probably not what you want to test with that test.

Comment: Also, what is the relation, if any, between `Class1` and `Class2`?

Comment: no, it is not necessary

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  In the unit test, you use copy.  If your class supports copy, why do you allocate it dynamically?  (As a general rule, if a class supports copy, you shouldn't use smart pointers with it, nor allocate it dynamically, because if you do, you'll end up with a horrible mix of dynamic and local objects.  Choose one or the other for each class.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be OK although it's a weird use case.

```
Class2 a = *(Class2::getInstanceOfClass1()); //suspected
```

What happens is that a `Class2` instance `a` is created by calling a ctor of `Class2` which takes the `Class1` returned in the shared pointer from `getInstanceOfClass1`. The nested temporary (the shared pointer) will then be deleted automatically **at the end of the expression**, deleting the `Class1` instance used to initialize `a` at the end of the whole expression.

Advice? Maybe you meant to write `Class1 a = ...`? In that case I suggest you consider

```
auto ap = Class2::getInstanceOfClass1();
int code = ap->useInputAndReturnCode(input);
```

to avoid creating copies of `Class1`.

Comment: Oh!! You are totally right... Being confidential about the real names of the classes, I did such mistake about "Class2 a" instead of "Class1 a". Gonna make an edit! Thanks already!

Comment: So I understand that "auto" will automatically get the type of the returned object, and then I see you can use the object "ap" without any cast.. A nice advice. Thanks! (I'm trying to upvote and they say I need reputation!...-__-)

Comment: @Farah `auto` is a C++11 thing, use it if you can. But be aware that `up`'s type is now `std::shared_ptr<Class1>`. If `auto` does not work, this is the type you should explicitly use for `a`. (BTW: Even with low rep you can accept an answer)

Comment: I've finally got the privilege(+1). Well, unfortunately, I can't use C++11. So I understand I can't use "auto".

Comment: @Farah Edited my last comment, as I often write `std` where you still need `boost`. I hope this hasn't caused any confusion for you...

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to free shared_ptr, as the pointed object is automatically destroyed when no shared_ptr points to it anymore.
On the other hand you have to make sure not to mix shared_ptr and regular pointers on the same object : if the object is destroyed by boost because no shared_ptr are pointing to it, you will get errors when trying to access it thanks to the regular pointer.